# Kaggle automatically sort ggplot alphabetically

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, kaggle

I want to ask how to solve this problem,
I have this code running in RStudio just fine:

```
  all_data_clean %>%
    group_by(member_casual, month) %>% 
    summarize(number_of_rides = n()) %>% 
    arrange(member_casual, month) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = month, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) +
    labs(title = "Total Number of Rides by Month") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30)) +
    geom_col(width=0.5, position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
    theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
```

Which produces something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34bUp.png)

But when I copy-paste that code to Kaggle, the graph turns like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgzVx.png)
Are my Kaggle settings wrong?
Thank you

Comment: You will have more chance of an answer if you post some data that allows the problem to be re-created. Use the R function `dput` and paste the results of this into the original question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.